# What is the correct way to configure Identity Server 3 for authorization code flow with SPAs?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, openid-connect, identityserver3

We have an instance of Identity Server 3 which has been used for some time with various clients, some using implicit flow, others using client credentials. We now have a new requirement to integrate an iOS native app with this identity provider. I understand these days implicit flow is not recommended and public facing apps should instead be using authorization code flow. Examples of such advice are [here](https://www.ubisecure.com/api/single-page-application-and-openid-connect/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544825/security-of-oauth2-client-id-and-client-secret/44545641#44545641).

By my understanding, authorization code flow has a step whereby a received authorization code is exchanged for JWT tokens via some back channel by supplying it alongside a client ID and secret. However, with SPAs and native apps we don't have the luxury of storing secrets. The guidance I [found here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/) would suggest I can simply omit the secret from the `connect/token` request, but my testing so far doesn't confirm this. So I'm stuck. To demonstrate, I've set up a client on my local instance of IS3 to test with:

```
{
    'clientId': 'test',
    'flow': 'AuthorizationCode',
    'name': 'test',
    'redirectUris': [ 'http://localhost:8080/' ], 
    'scopes': ['openid','profile']
}
```

I then make the following `GET` request to my IdP:

`[ID_PROVIDER]/connect/authorize?client_id=test&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&scope=openid%20profile&response_type=code`

This lets me sign in and returns me to my test app running at http://localhost:8080 with my authorization code in the querystring.

I now try to exchange this code for JWT tokens by `POST`ing to `[ID_PROVIDER]/connect/token` with the following body: `code=[AUTH_CODE]&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080`

But Identity Server rejects this with an HTTP 400 and `invalid_client` error. When I dig into its logs I see a `ClientSecretValidator` event with message "No client secret found". Which kind of makes sense based on my understanding outlined above, but given people are recommending using this flow for public-facing apps I must be misunderstanding something.

If anyone could clarify that'd be great, thanks.

Comment: Your title says SPA but from your question it sounds like you want to authenticate from a native iOS app. Which one is it?

Comment: I realise I jump between the two but I'm not sure it matters all that much. They're both a client application that cannot be trusted with secrets so in terms of their OIDC configuration they would be treated the same I'd have thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just omit the client secret. For your native case, I'd consider embedding the secret within the app. The authorize request will still have to validate the return_uri (custom URI scheme for your native app) and if that still feels insecure, you can also lean on Proof of possession (PoP) tokens (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/pop/overview.html).

For a SPA app I would keep it implicit flow, I see no point in doing secrets there.